# Help with vectorial analysis exercise

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $D(0,r)  :=  \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \|x\| \leq r }\right\}$ and $f:D(0,r) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous differentiable function in the interior of $D(0,r)$. I'm trying to show that, if $f$ is constant in the boundary of $D(0,r)$, then there exists $X_0$ in the interior of $D(0,r)$ such that $\bigtriangledown f(X_0)=\vec0$.

I tried several tricks like applying the mean value theorem in a specific direction but it wasn't enough. Could you please give me some hints that don't solve immediately the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $ f $ is constant along the boundary and $ f $ is not constant in the interior, then, since $ f$ is continuous it takes a maximum and minimum value in the interior. What is the gradient of $ f $ at a critical point?